# Parallel Integration testing with DBContext concurrent issue

Tags: c#, integration-testing, xunit, dbcontext, testcontainers

I have integration tests having the base class which creates Docker Db container per test class:

```
public class ApiFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Program>, IAsyncLifetime
{
    private readonly PostgreSqlContainer _postgreSqlContainer =
        new PostgreSqlBuilder().WithDatabase("Tests").Build();

    public Task InitializeAsync() => _postgreSqlContainer.StartAsync();
    Task IAsyncLifetime.DisposeAsync() => _postgreSqlContainer.DisposeAsync().AsTask();

    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddTransient<IEmailSender>(_ => new StubEmailSender());
            services.SetDockerContainerDatabaseAsync(_postgreSqlContainer.GetConnectionString()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        });
    }
}

public static async Task SetDockerContainerDatabaseAsync(this IServiceCollection services, string connectionString)
{
    services.RemoveAll(typeof(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext>));
    services.RemoveAll(typeof(DbContextOptions<MessageDbContext>));

    services.AddDbContextPool<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseNpgsql(connectionString));
    services.AddDbContextPool<MessageDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseNpgsql(connectionString));

    var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

    await serviceProvider.EnsureDbCreatedAsync<ApplicationDbContext>();
    await serviceProvider.EnsureDbMigratedAsync<MessageDbContext>();
}
```

And `BaseIntegrationTest` implementing the `ApiFactory`:

```cs
public class BaseIntegrationTest : IClassFixture<ApiFactory>
{
    protected readonly ApiFactory _factory;
    public HttpClient ApiClient { get; set; }

    public BaseIntegrationTest(ApiFactory factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
        ApiClient = _factory.CreateClient();
    }
}
```

Then integration test class which tests if `MessageService` sends an Email properly:

```cs
public class MessageServiceTests : BaseIntegrationTest
{
    public MessageServiceTests(ApiFactory factory) : base(factory) { }

    [Fact]
    public async Task SendRegisterConfirmationEmail_Failed_InsertMessageQueue()
    {
        // Required Arranges...

        using var scope = _factory.Services.CreateScope();
        var messageQueueRepository = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MessageQueueRepository>();
        var messageService = new MessageService(emailSenderMock.Object, messageQueueRepository);

        // Sends an email and inserts message to the database via MessageQueueRepository
        await messageService.SendRegisterConfirmationEmailAsync(email, confirmationLink);

        //Verifies that event handler was called (which inserts data to database)
        emailSenderMock.Verify(e => e.SendAsync(email, RegisterConfirmation.SUBJECT, body), Times.Once);

        //Checks that message was inserted to the database
        var addedMessage = await messageQueueRepository.GetOneByCondition(m => m.To == email && m.From == _senderEmail && m.Status == MessageStatus.Failed).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        Assert.NotNull(addedMessage);
    }
}
```

There is another test looking almost the same and also another test class (but for each test class there is a dedicated PostgreSQL database docker container) which also checks by using `MessageQueueRepository` and `MessageDbContext` if the entity was added to the table.

When I run those tests on my local machine everything is fine, but when I put it on CI under Ubuntu machine it gives me randomly:

> A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same instance of DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext

or

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index')

And the line causing the issue is:

```
var addedMessage = await messageQueueRepository.GetOneByCondition(m => m.To == email && m.From == _senderEmail && m.Status == MessageStatus.Failed).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

And I know, this is because I went into the case where those 3 tests were run on the same time and cause `MessageDbContext` to throw BUT question is, can I somehow handle dependency injection here to still run tests in parallel? Maybe I should create scope somehow differently, or there is no other way than making them run separate/sequential.

`GetOneByCondition` code:

```
public virtual IQueryable<TDbModel> GetOneByCondition(
    Expression<Func<TDbModel, bool>> conditionPredicate,
    bool tracking = false,
    params string[] includes)
{
    var queryableEntities = tracking ? GetDbSet() : GetDbSet().AsNoTracking();

    RepositoryHelper<TDbModel>.Include(ref queryableEntities, includes);
    RepositoryHelper<TDbModel>.ApplyCondition(ref queryableEntities, conditionPredicate);

    return queryableEntities;
}

public static void ApplyCondition(ref IQueryable<TDbModel> queryableEntities, Expression<Func<TDbModel, bool>>? conditionPredicate)
{
    if (conditionPredicate != null)
        queryableEntities = queryableEntities.Where(conditionPredicate);
}

public static void Include(ref IQueryable<TDbModel> queryableEntities, string[] includes)
{
    if (includes != null)
    {
        foreach (var include in includes.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)))
        {
            queryableEntities = queryableEntities.Include(include);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what is a problem here. But in general I'd say you are mixing test types here. Write integration tests of `MessageQueueRepository` against docker. Write unit tests of `MessageService`. Then write the web application integration tests of its public api (REST or whatever api this service exposes).

Comment: I'm running the web application integration tests of its public API and would like to have tests running in pararell against MessageDbContext, `MessageService` sends an email and inserts `MessageModel` entity via `MessageQueueRepository` to the table and then I would like to make a check by `MessageQueueReposiotry` or `MessageDbContext` that entity was added properly.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you are trying to do. Let me try to explain my-self in a bit longer answer

Answer (score 0):

First, a few general notes about your test.

- You are doing a "strange" thing. You are starting an application, **retrieving** the `MessageQueueRepository` instance from the DI, **mocking** `EmailSender`, and **creating** a new instance of `MessageService`. This is a strange hybrid of the system under test. It would be much more logical (IMO) to replace the `EmailSender` implementation in the DI with a mock, then retrieve the `MessageService`.
- On the other hand, I can see here a mix of a few test levels. Instead of doing what you are doing, you need to write the following tests:

1. Cover the `MessageQueueRepository` with **integration tests** against real DB (don't try to mock DbContext). You don't need to start the whole service with DI for that. Just create an instance of `MessageQueueRepository` and pass the `DbContext` instance configured to run against docker into the constructor.
2. Cover the `MessageService` with **unit tests**. Mock all the dependencies and verify it behaves as you expect.
3. Cover the public service API with **integration tests** using the `ApiFactory`. You can replace external dependencies with mocks in the DI.

This way, you will achieve better code coverage and less fragile tests.
Now regarding the following error:

> A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same instance of DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext

This is not necessarily a concurrency problem. And most probably, you could reproduce it with the `MessageQueueRepository` integration tests without the complexity of your current test implementation. This code has a `.FirstOrDefaultAsync()` at the end

```cs
var addedMessage = await messageQueueRepository
    .GetOneByCondition(m => m.To == email && m.From == _senderEmail && m.Status == MessageStatus.Failed)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

This makes me think the method `GetOneByCondition` returns `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`. Am I right? Somewhere in the `GetOneByCondition` implementation, you are querying data from one or more tables, then converting the `IQueriable` to `IAsyncEnumerable`, implicitly or explicitly, then iterating it and using its result to query another table. The problem with this approach is iterating `IAsyncEnumerable` is still an active operation against the database. So if you try to make another request to DB, it will fail with the mentioned error.

If I'm wrong, please share the `GetOneByCondition` implementation because I'm 99.9% sure the problem is there.

Comment: `GetOneByCondition` returns `IQueryable<TDbModel>`. It basically gets DbSet and uses `.Where` on it and returns queryable entities
I'll post this method body in the main topic

Comment: Oh, this is a Generic Repository pattern. TBH, I never understood why people do it with EF. By exposing `tracking` and `includes` arguments, you declare you are using EF behind the scenes. All exceptions will be from EF namespace. So what's the point in using it? Just my thoughts, you don't have to answer this question :)

Comment: Your code looks correct. The problem is perhaps somewhere else, not in the shown code.